# How to hover a search box under sub header in ionic?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

So, I want to hover a search box under a sub header in ionic after pressing the search icon button as shown in the image below. The most important thing I want to achieve is, if I scroll the list downwards, the search box must hover below.
Therefore how can I do this ?. I'm using ionic version one.

[image]